# SPARQL - Get object properties and exact type of datatype properties of a class

Tags: types, properties, sparql

I want to get all the properties of a class.
If a property is a datatype property I want to know its exact type i.e. float, integer, date etc.

Running the following query I get only if a property is an object property or a datatype property

```
SELECT ?class ?property ?type
WHERE {
    ?resource ?property ?target .
    ?property rdfs:domain ?class .
    ?resource a ?class .
    ?property rdf:type ?type .
```

}

**Results**

```
:Store  :location http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ObjectProperty
:Product :price http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#DatatypeProperty
```

How can I specify the type of a property if it is a datatype property?
For example, I would like to know not only that price is a DatatypeProperty but it is a float.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatype gets specified as the range (`rdfs:range`) of a datatype property.

```
SELECT ?class ?property ?type ?range
WHERE {

    ?resource ?property ?target .
    ?resource a ?class .
    ?property rdf:type ?type .

    OPTIONAL {    
      ?property rdfs:domain ?class .
    }

    OPTIONAL {
      ?property rdfs:range ?range .
    }

}
```

(I used `OPTIONAL` so that your query also lists properties for which no domain and/or range is specified.)

Result: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lZaz.png)